# Excel VBA: setting a range value within a function (not a sub) not possible?

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner at Excel VBA.

I would like to invoke a function `'getGraph'` taking as argument the 3 areas not in yellow in the picture below.

However, the function needs to do a `vlookup`, and therefore i would like to  compute the area in yellow, which would be used as a key for the vlookup. I then plan to use `Range.Resize()` to refer to the extended range for the vlookup.

I do not want the user to enter this yellow area , because the function needs to understand how the key is constructed  based on the data it is passed in.

Now my understanding (from experimentation -- see below) is this:

1. within a function (`Function`), such as `'getGraph'` i cannot set a range value, and therefore I cannot setup the yellow area. Is this correct ? I do not see this explicitly mentioned in the various tutorial websites i have seen on the internet. Is there explicit documentation for this ? I looked here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range(object) and here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/calling-sub-and-function-procedures and on numerous other websites
2. I can use a macro (ie a `Sub`) to set range values, and therefore compute the yellow area. However I find the way to invoke macros a bit convoluted. Is there a way of entering a macro name in a cell, like a function , so that pressing F2 on the cell would invoke the macro ? this would be a bit easier for the user.
3. the function `'getGraph'` is actually an array function. Is it invoked from macros as per normal ?

[image]

The experimentation I did:

```
' works - returns "hello" in its cell
Function tester0() As String

    tester0 = "hello"
    
End Function

' does not work - seems a function cannot have a side-effect
Function tester1() As String

    Range("A1").Value = "hi"
    tester1 = "hello"
    
End Function

' does not work -- seems a function cannot invoke a sub
Function tester2() As String

    tester2Sub
    tester2 = "hello"
    
End Function

' works but must be invoked via ALT-F8 or some published shortcut
Sub tester2Sub()

    Range("A1").Value = "hi"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no own effort.

Comment: @variatus I did say i had experimented, hence my assertions. where does it answer my questions, say here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range(object) ? or here: https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/study/vba-sub-vs-function/ ? i have searched through numerous documents.

Comment: Thisis what i used btw: Function tester0() As String

    tester0 = "hello"
    
End Function


Function tester1() As String

    Range("A1").Value = "hi"
    tester1 = "hello"
    
End Function

Function tester2() As String

    tester2Sub
    tester2 = "hello"
    
End Function

Sub tester2Sub()

    Range("A1").Value = "hi"
    
End Sub

Comment: Please modify your question to include the code you tried. It's a vital part of it and needs to be shown where it can be read and copied - the question's body, between code tags.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel#:~:text=A%20user%2Ddefined%20function%20called,Change%20another%20cell's%20value.